# unable to get webview to show video fullscreen

Tags: android, video, webview, fullscreen, webchromeclient

i have created an android application to preview my website that has mp4 video player, it works fine but im unable to preview it on full screen when i click on video enlarge icon.
Please note that im a new to this , been only learning this for 3 days
 This is the code MainActivity.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

// variables for camera and choosing files methods
private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;

// the same for Android 5.0 methods only
private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
private String mCameraPhotoPath;

// error handling
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // define url that will open in webView
    String webViewUrl = "http://test.com";

    // webView code without handling external links
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    //webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    //webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

    // load url in webView
    webView.loadUrl(webViewUrl);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());

    // implement WebChromeClient inner class
    // we will define openFileChooser for select file from camera
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        // page loading progress, gone when fully loaded
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            if (progress < 100 && progressBar.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
            }
            progressBar.setProgress(progress);
            if (progress == 100) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
            }
        }

        // for Lollipop, all in one
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
                mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
            }
            mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;

            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

                // create the file where the photo should go
                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
                }

                // continue only if the file was successfully created
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                            Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                } else {
                    takePictureIntent = null;
                }
            }

            Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");

            Intent[] intentArray;
            if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
            } else {
                intentArray = new Intent[0];
            }

            Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, getString(R.string.image_chooser));
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

            return true;
        }

        // creating image files (Lollipop only)
        private File createImageFile() throws IOException {

            File imageStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "DirectoryNameHere");

            if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
            }

            // create an image file name
            imageStorageDir  = new File(imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
            return imageStorageDir;
        }

        // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;

            try {
                File imageStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "DirectoryNameHere");

                if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                    imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
                }

                File file = new File(imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");

                mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file); // save to the private variable

                final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
                // captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION, ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");

                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, getString(R.string.image_chooser));
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Parcelable[]{captureIntent});

                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Camera Exception:" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

        // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
        }

        // openFileChooser for other Android versions
        /* may not work on KitKat due to lack of implementation of openFileChooser() or onShowFileChooser()
           https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62220
           however newer versions of KitKat fixed it on some devices */
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
        }

    });

}

// return here when file selected from camera or from SD Card
@Override
public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    // code for all versions except of Lollipop
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

        if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
            if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                return;
            }

            Uri result=null;

            try{
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                    result = null;
                } else {
                    // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                    result = data == null ? mCapturedImageURI : data.getData();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :"+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }

    } // end of code for all versions except of Lollipop

    // start of code for Lollipop only
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

        if (requestCode != FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }

        Uri[] results = null;

        // check that the response is a good one
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data == null || data.getData() == null) {
                // if there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                }
            } else {
                String dataString = data.getDataString();
                if (dataString != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                }
            }
        }

        mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
        mFilePathCallback = null;

    } // end of code for Lollipop only

}

// handling back button
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
}
```

And This is activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.test.app.MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/content_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

How Do i continue my code to get video full screen support

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Please note that it does work on android chrome browser but it doesnt in my code

Comment: I dont know why some people keep low-rating my questions ! Is it a mistake that i posted here !!! Anyways no one seems to reply !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

In Manifest file

```
 <activity
            android:name="your activity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" />
```

Comment: Open the video in new activity and for that activity use above code

Comment: And whats the activity name ? forgive me im an android noob :'(

Comment: Or how do i build this activity ?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. It's my mistake.